# Change column in-place with copy-on-write

Tags: python, pandas, in-place, copy-on-write

I have a large DataFrame. I have enabled [copy_on_write](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/copy_on_write.html), as is expected to be the default for 3.0. I want to limit the values of some of the columns (in-place). Like this:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.options.mode.copy_on_write = True
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': '.', 'x': [1, 2, 3]})
df['x'].clip(lower=0, inplace=True)
```

This gives me a `ChainedAssignmentError`:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> DataFrame or Series through chained assignment using an inplace
> method.
> When using the Copy-on-Write mode, such inplace method never
> works to update the original DataFrame or Series, because the
> intermediate object on which we are setting values always behaves as a
> copy.
>
> For example, when doing `df[col].method(value, inplace=True)`, try
> using `df.method({col: value}, inplace=True)` instead, to perform the
> operation inplace on the original object.

How is this supposed to work? I tried variations of the suggestion in the last paragraph and other things, but I keep getting the error.

Comment: what is the expected goal of using CoW here?

Comment: Just preparing for the default in 3.0...

Comment: Hi, not sure to understand why `inplace` is needed here: if you simply have one statement, why not assign back to the column? And if you need clipping to happen in chain assignments, why not use `assign`?

Comment: For one, I hoped `inplace` would save memory, which is tight.

Comment: I have a similar problem to yours where Pandas now warns against updating operations using iloc on a large Dataframe.
No easy solution as far as I can see from reading the docs on this topic:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/copy_on_write.html